# How to use dictionary

Tags: python, list

How do I make 2d lists in run time when user inputs some number.

Comment: This question is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657236/find-letter-of-words-in-a-matrix-diagonally

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Letter of Words in a Matrix Diagonally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657236/find-letter-of-words-in-a-matrix-diagonally)

Comment: @PranjalDoshi the post you linked is different. It's somewhat similar but doesn't answer what I actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are easy and difficult things:

- horizontal ist trivial - simply join the inner list and replace the word and the word reversed by its upper case representation, then split the string into letters
- vertical is mildly more difficult, but you can handle it by transposing the matrix via `zip` and after replacing transpose again
- vertical is handled in the linked question [Find Letter of Words in a Matrix Diagonally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657236/find-letter-of-words-in-a-matrix-diagonally)

**Here is how to do horizontal and vertical:**

```
data  = [['l', 'd', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'p'],
         ['i', 't', 'i', 'f', 'w', 'f'],
         ['g', 'n', 'r', 'k', 'q', 'u'],
         ['h', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'l', 'l'],
         ['t', 'c', 'v', 'g', 't', 'l'],
         ['d', 'r', 'a', 'w', 'c', 's']]

words = ['draw', 'full', 'hold', 'laugh', 'light', 'start', 'all', 'kid']

from pprint import pprint as p

for w in words: 
    print()
    # horizontal
    data1 = [list(''.join(line).replace(w,w.upper())) for line in data]
    # horizontal, word reversed
    data1 = [list(''.join(line).replace(w[::-1],w[::-1].upper())) for line in data1]

    # vertical
    data1 = list(zip(*[list(''.join(line).replace(w,w.upper()))  
                       for line in zip(*data1)]))
    # vertical, word reversed
    data1 = list(zip(*[list(''.join(line).replace(w[::-1],w[::-1].upper())) 
                       for line in zip(*data1)]))

    if data1 != data:
        print(f"Found: {w}:")
        data = data1
        p(data)
    else:
        print(f"No {w} - check diagonally")
```

Output:

```
Found: draw:
[('l', 'd', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'p'),
 ('i', 't', 'i', 'f', 'w', 'f'),
 ('g', 'n', 'r', 'k', 'q', 'u'),
 ('h', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'l', 'l'),
 ('t', 'c', 'v', 'g', 't', 'l'),
 ('D', 'R', 'A', 'W', 'c', 's')]

Found: full:
[('l', 'd', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'p'),
 ('i', 't', 'i', 'f', 'w', 'F'),
 ('g', 'n', 'r', 'k', 'q', 'U'),
 ('h', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'l', 'L'),
 ('t', 'c', 'v', 'g', 't', 'L'),
 ('D', 'R', 'A', 'W', 'c', 's')]

Found: hold:
[('l', 'D', 'L', 'O', 'H', 'p'),
 ('i', 't', 'i', 'f', 'w', 'F'),
 ('g', 'n', 'r', 'k', 'q', 'U'),
 ('h', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'l', 'L'),
 ('t', 'c', 'v', 'g', 't', 'L'),
 ('D', 'R', 'A', 'W', 'c', 's')]

Found: laugh:
[('l', 'D', 'L', 'O', 'H', 'p'),
 ('i', 't', 'i', 'f', 'w', 'F'),
 ('g', 'n', 'r', 'k', 'q', 'U'),
 ('H', 'G', 'U', 'A', 'L', 'L'),
 ('t', 'c', 'v', 'g', 't', 'L'),
 ('D', 'R', 'A', 'W', 'c', 's')]

No light - check diagonally
No start - check diagonally
No all - check diagonally
No kid - check diagonally
```

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal you can use this:

```
>>> for i in range(len(l)):# l is the list
    temp = ''.join(l[i])
    x = temp.find(word) #word is the user input eg. draw
    y = len(word)
    if x != -1:
        for j in range(y):
            l[i][j]=l[i][j].capitalize()
```

I'll try to make for vertical and diagonal as well

Comment: It doesn't work properly. It makes wrong capitalizations for some words. Try inputting 'hold' and 'all'.

Answer (score 0):

this one:

```
l = [['l', 'd', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'p'],  
    ['i', 't', 'i', 'f', 'w', 'f'],   
    ['g', 'n', 'r', 'k', 'q', 'u'],  
    ['h', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'l', 'l'],  
    ['t', 'c', 'v', 'g', 't', 'l'],   
    ['d', 'r', 'a', 'w', 'c', 's']]

word = input("Please enter a word: ")

for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l[i])):
        if l[i][j] in word:
            l[i][j]=l[i][j].capitalize()

print(l)
```

outs:

```
Please enter a word: hello
[['L', 'd', 'L', 'O', 'H', 'p'], ['i', 't', 'i', 'f', 'w', 'f'], ['g', 'n', 'r', 'k', 'q', 'u'], ['H', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'L', 'L'], ['t', 'c', 'v', 'g', 't', 'L'], ['d', 'r', 'a', 'w', 'c', 's']]
```

Comment: Its difficult to understand for me. For example if you input “hello” what you’re want to get?